# String concatenation of interpolated variables

Tags: ruby, string

The code below is longer than the recommended 80 characters.

I've tried to break it up and concatenate it with + operator and `<<` operator, but it doesn't seem to work. I've tried the `.to_s` method and moved the colons into their own string but to no avail.

What would be the correct way to split this up onto 2 or 3 lines without getting the `no method "+@":String` error?

```
string = "#{sprintf("%02i", hours)}:#{sprintf("%02i", minutes)}:#{sprintf("%02i", seconds)}"
```

Comment: If you would have a `Time` object instead of your `hour`, `minute`, `second` integers, you could use [`time.strftime(%H:%M:%S)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime).

Comment: Please edit to show your desired output.

Comment: I tried this but I dont think time is part of ruby so it gave me an error saying time wasnt defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine the three `sprintf` into one:

```
string = sprintf("%02i:%02i:%02i", hours, minutes, seconds)
```

Comment: NOT the answer to question

Comment: @AndreyDeineko If the question is a general *how to split a line that includes string interpolated variables into multiple lines*, you are right. However, it's not, in this specific problem, the line is long **because** OP's code uses unnecessary string interpolation.

Comment: Okay thanks for this, I could learn from this because I forgot sprintf was essentially the same as printf in java

Answer (score 1):

To split string into multiline in Ruby you use backslash:

```
string = "#{sprintf("%02i", hours)}: \
#{sprintf("%02i", minutes)}: \
#{sprintf("%02i", seconds)}"
```

Notice how there is only one opening and one closing `"`.

You can also consider moving three calls to `sprintf` method into one.

Comment: why minus? it is the answer to OP question. who did it? :)

Comment: what exactly happens to the space between that colon and the backslash? Is all the white space just removed due to the \?

Comment: @Jeff if you put backslash without a space after `:`, there will be no space

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your real question is that, given numbers of seconds or a time object, you want to construct a string with the desired format.

If you are given `seconds`:

```
def fmt(seconds)
  hours, minutes = seconds.divmod(60)
  "%02d, %02d, %02d" % [hours, *minutes.divmod(60)]
end

fmt(223)
  #=> "03, 00, 43"
```

If you are given a `Time` object:

```
require 'time'

def fmt(time)
  time.strftime('%H hours, %M minutes, %S seconds')
end

time = Time.now
  #=> 2015-05-16 14:38:02 -0700 
fmt(time)
  #=> "14 hours, 38 minutes, 02 seconds"
```

In this second case I added the words "hours", "minutes" and "seconds" just to illustrate how the format string could be modified.

If you want to print this on multiple lines, simply insert newlines (`\n`) in the appropriate format string.

Comment: Just a quick question. Im not understanding why you do hours,minutes = seconds.divmod(6). The six there isnt making mathematical sense to me..

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, Jeff. It should have been `60`.